# Team Foundation Server - how to test locally?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm a [LAMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) developer through and through, but I've been handed an ASP.NET project built using TFS. Sorting the code isn't much of a problem; I can figure most of that out, but TFS is doing my head in.

What are the steps I need to take to be able to test the website source locally on my own computer?

I've got [IIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services) installed and localhost is able to show .asp and .aspx pages, but it looks like the source code stored locally by Visual Studio isn't configured to actually run - it needs to be "built" before it'll function as a site.

The documentation I've ploughed through seems to have been written by... well... Microsoft, so despite everything probably being perfectly logical it makes no sense.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with TFS, and everything to do with the fact that you don't understand ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, John, and that's why I'm here. Thanks for your snarky comment.

Comment: It wasn't meant to be snarky. It was meant to indicate the area you should study. It won't help you much to read "TFS" books - you need to read "ASP.NET" books. Snarky would be something like, "this is what happens when you send a LAMP developer to do a man's job", but I would never say such a thing, lest the shoe some day be on the other foot.

Comment: That's fine then - and please accept that I am studying, have ordered books but it still doesn't help me relieve the pressure of having to get this local test sorted ASAP before said books even arrive ^^

Comment: I had no doubt that you were studying. I only hoped to ensure that the focus of your study should be "ASP.NET" and not "TFS", since you current issue is not related to TFS. See http://asp.net for ASP.NET resources, http://iis.net for IIS-specific questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up your development environment has nothing to do with TFS. Since you have clearly got the code, you've finished with TFS until you want to make a change (or log a work item like a defect).

You need to set up IIS, and make sure the Visual Studio project is configured to match.

1. Note the path of the ASP.NET project folder (*not* the solution folder).
2. In IIS, create a new web application

   - Mapping to the path noted above
   - Associate with a application pool using the correct version of .NET.
   - You might want to increase the timeout of that application pool to make debugging easier: having the request timeout in the middle of a complex debugging session is annoying. (I normally create a debug application pool for each .NET version I'm working with).
3. Run Visual Studio as administrator
4. Open the solution.
5. In the web application's project's properties under "Web", set the path to the web application created in IIS. This can be set globally (will be saved in the project file) or locally (only affects this machine).

NB. IIS Express avoids the need to run as administrator and provides (as I understand) all the functionality of IIS for development and debugging.

Comment: That makes sense - will have a crack at sorting that. Thanks for the clear instructions!

Comment: Great - that's got the site running... now I just need to work through the various ASP errors :/

Comment: Just as a FYI - it's possible to get it all running on IIS, but it's a LOT easier to use Visual Studio's inbuilt server. Just download all the source files via the TFS link, then re-open the source files via the .sln you will have downloaded and then you can local test via Visual Studio.

Comment: @hfiggen: The VS test server "Casini" is very much cut down, there are many capabilities it doesn't have (SSL for a start). IIS Express is a better option for all but the simplest of sites.